# Android when my app switches orientation 2+ times I get nullPointerException

Tags: android

In my app there is 1 Activity(Activity A) and 3 Fragments (Frag B, Frag C, Frag D).  The process goes Activity A -> Frag B -> Frag C -> Frag D.  My app can do screen orientations but when I am on Frag D or Frag C and I do 1 screen orientation change its fine and the app still works.  Its when I  do 2+ screen orientation changes my savedInstanceState and everything that I have saved in my Activity A becomes null and I get a nullPointerException, so when I click "back" to go to the previous fragment the app crashes.

I can't really put my finger on why this is happening but hopefully someone might have an idea as to why this is happening, I would think that if 1 screen orientation works then why would the second one do this?  It doesn't matter if I start in landscape or portrait but its just when 2+ orientation changes happen.  I am not too sure what code to put in here without making this very lengthy.

EDIT. LOGCAT:

```
11-12 20:44:46.637: I/Activity A(998): onStart
11-12 20:44:46.637: I/Activity A(998): onResume
11-12 20:46:18.947: I/Frag B(998): onCreateView
11-12 20:46:19.157: I/Frag B(998): onStart
11-12 20:46:19.157: I/Frag B(998): onResume
11-12 20:46:23.057: I/Frag B(998): onPause
11-12 20:46:23.067: I/Frag B(998): onStop
11-12 20:46:23.067: I/Frag C(998): onCreateView
11-12 20:46:23.327: I/Frag C(998): onStart
11-12 20:46:23.327: I/Frag C(998): onResume
11-12 20:46:25.507: I/Frag C(998): onPause
11-12 20:46:25.507: I/Frag C(998): onStop
11-12 20:46:25.527: I/Frag D(998): onCreateView
11-12 20:46:29.466: I/Frag D(998): onStart
11-12 20:46:29.466: I/Frag D(998): onResume

//First screen rotation.

11-12 20:46:52.907: I/Frag D(998): onPause
11-12 20:46:52.907: I/Activity A(998): onPause
11-12 20:46:52.907: I/System.out(998): savedInstanceState in Frag C = Bundle[{LibraryChoice=Fighter}]
11-12 20:46:52.907: I/System.out(998): savedInstanceState in Frag D = Bundle[{LibraryChoice=Fighter, LibraryChoiceSelected=FighterSelected}]
11-12 20:46:52.947: I/Frag D(998): onStop
11-12 20:46:52.947: I/Activity A(998): onStop
11-12 20:46:52.957: I/Frag B(998): onDestroy
11-12 20:46:52.957: I/Frag C(998): onDestroy
11-12 20:46:53.037: I/Frag D(998): onDestroy
11-12 20:46:53.037: I/Activity A(998): onDestroy
11-12 20:46:53.667: I/Frag D(998): onCreateView
11-12 20:46:57.127: I/Frag D(998): onStart
11-12 20:46:57.127: I/Activity A(998): onStart
11-12 20:46:57.147: I/Activity A(998): onResume
11-12 20:46:57.147: I/Frag D(998): onResume

//Second screen rotation.

11-12 20:47:05.697: I/Frag D(998): onPause
11-12 20:47:05.697: I/Activity A(998): onPause
11-12 20:47:05.697: I/System.out(998): savedInstanceState in Frag C = Bundle[{LibraryChoice=null}]
11-12 20:47:05.697: I/System.out(998): savedInstanceState in Frag D = Bundle[{LibraryChoice=Fighter, LibraryChoiceSelected=FighterSelected}]
11-12 20:47:05.737: I/Frag D(998): onStop
11-12 20:47:05.737: I/Activity A(998): onStop
11-12 20:47:05.747: I/Frag B(998): onDestroy
11-12 20:47:05.747: I/Frag C(998): onDestroy
11-12 20:47:05.867: I/Frag D(998): onDestroy
11-12 20:47:05.867: I/Activity A(998): onDestroy
11-12 20:47:06.457: I/Frag D(998): onCreateView
11-12 20:47:09.907: I/Frag D(998): onStart
11-12 20:47:09.907: I/Activity A(998): onStart
11-12 20:47:09.917: I/Activity A(998): onResume
11-12 20:47:09.917: I/Frag D(998): onResume

//Back button pressed.

11-12 20:47:19.696: I/Frag D(998): onPause
11-12 20:47:19.696: I/Frag D(998): onStop
11-12 20:47:19.707: I/Frag C(998): onCreateView
11-12 20:47:19.977: D/AndroidRuntime(998): Shutting down VM
11-12 20:47:20.017: E/AndroidRuntime(998): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 20:47:20.017: E/AndroidRuntime(998): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 20:47:20.017: E/AndroidRuntime(998): at j.l.ls11.FragB.onCreateView(FragB.java:99)
```

Anyone know how to get my Frag C to not be null?

Comment: I wish SO had quick comment buttons, e.g. one to make a "please post your logcat comment". So, please post your logcat.  It is not safe to assume that if something works once, it will work again.  static x =1; y = 3; z = y / x; x =  x-1; z = y / x; - will crash on second call.

Comment: What do you mean by “everything that I have saved in my Activity A”? Are you talking about data in the activity object, or data saved in instance state bundle?

Comment: @Simon Added logcat, sorry for the delay on the post.

Comment: @BastienLéonard I have interfaces in my fragments that store what the user selects in my fragments so in my other fragments I can retrieve them.  But actually both are becoming null, my savedInstanceState and the data in my activity object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was have the fragments communicate both ways.  I just had it as B->C->D and didn't have D->C->B.  Once I had them passing information that way it worked. :)